# Shell script - Read CSV file lines and add prefix for multiple values in a cell

Tags: shell-script

I have a csv file like this.

```
aaa|c1|bbb|t1
bbb|c1,c2|nnn|t1,t2
```

The pipe is the delimiter. I want to generate a string with columns 2 and 4. And I need to add a prefix for both column values.

Column 2 = `a` is the prefix
column 4 = `b` is the prefix

#### Expected output:

```
this is final string a.c1=b.t1
this is final string a.c1,a.c2=-b.t1,b,t2
```

#### My sample script (in complete):

```
while read r_line
do
c2 = $(echo $r_line|awk -F'|' '{print $2}')
c4 = $(echo $r_file |awk -F'|' '{print $4}')
out=$("this is final string a.$c2=b.$c4")
done < csv file
```

Here if the c2 or t2 has comma-separated values I need to apply the prefix for both the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using sed.

```bsh
prefix1=a.
prefix2=b.
while read r_line; do
    c2=$(echo $r_line | cut -d'|' -f2)
    c4=$(echo $r_line | cut -d'|' -f4)
    s1=$(echo $c2 | sed "s/,/,$prefix1/g" | sed "s/^/$prefix1/g")
    s2=$(echo $c4 | sed "s/,/,$prefix2/g" | sed "s/^/$prefix2/g")
    echo "this is final string $s1=$s2"
done
```

The script search `,` and instead with `,$prefix` and finally add `$prefix` at head.
And I like to use `cut` to split strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all within `bash` by reading the csv file into an array and then outputting the 2nd nd 4th fields by first doing parameter substitution within them

```
while IFS='|' read -ra a;do
  echo This is the final string: \
    "a.${a[1]//,/,a.}=b.${a[3]//,/,b.}"
done < csvfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read each line, use `cut` to get each field and the use `sed` on them.

```
while read -r line; do
a="$(cut -d'|' -f2 <<<"$line")"
b="$(cut -d'|' -f4 <<<"$line")"
a="$(echo "$a"|sed -e 's/^/a./' -e 's/,/,a./g')"
b="$(echo "$b"|sed -e 's/^/b./' -e 's/,/,b./g')"
echo "this is final string $a=$b"
done < csv_file
```

Answer (score 0):

full awk solution

awk file (se.awk )

```
BEGIN { FS="|" }
{
  a="" ; n=split($2,A,",") ; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) a = a ",a." A[i] ;
  b="" ; n=split($4,B,",") ; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) b = b ",b." B[i] ;
  printf "%s %s=%s\n",prefix,substr(a,2),substr(b,2) ;
}
```

called as

```
awk -v prefix="this is final string" -f se.awk c
this is final string a.c1=b.t1
this is final string a.c1,a.c2=b.t1,b.t2
```

where

- `-v prefix="this is final string"`  set var `prefix` in command line
- `BEGIN { FS="|" }` tell awk to use `|` as separator
- `a="" ; n=split($2,A,",")` split second field on `,` and count
- `for (i=1;i<=n;i++) a = a ",a." A[i]`  build expected string with a leading unwanted comma
- (same goes for b on fourth position )
- `prefix="this is final string"`  assemble string using printf, striping comma

if prefix is fixed, it can be insert in `awk` program

```
BEGIN { 
  FS="|" ;
  prefix="this is prefix" ; 
}
```